# How to simulate mouse clicks to a DirectX application in background?

Tags: c++, mouseevent, mouse

I need to send some mouse clicks to a DirectX application covered by other windows while doing stuffs in the foreground. To other applications I uses `SendMessage` and it works well, however it won't work with DirectX apps. `SendInput` doesn't make sense because it controls your cursor directly and requires the window to be foreground. I want it does that completely background. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can remember, you can send Win32 events to a DirectX application too using `SendMessage`. Why isn't it possible?

Comment: @Rakete1111 It's in fact an Android emulator. I tried `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` but no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 20191226: Just discovered that the Nox Android emulator listens mouse click events on the parent window rather than the rendering window. `PostMessage` to the parent window solves my problem.

```
00151044 "NoxAppPlayer" Qt5QWindowIcon                 <--Outmost window
└─ ...
└─ 00151264 "ScreenBoardClassWindow" Qt5QWindowIcon    <--PostMessage mouse event to this window
   └─ 002A05EA "sub" subWin                            <-- Screen renders on this window
└─ ...
```

> Finally I used a completely different method: using ADB provided in
>   Android emulator. Just `adb connect` to the port which the emulator
>   used and simplly `adb shell input tap [x] [y]` solves my problem.